# Runtimeerror : The size of tensor a (64) must match the size of tensor b (7) at non-singleton dimension 1

Tags: python, pytorch, conv-neural-network

I am trying to modify in a custom loss function in my code:

This is the existing code saample

```
class AFL(nn.Module):
    
    def __init__(self, delta=0.7, gamma=2., epsilon=1e-07):
        super(AFL, self).__init__()
        self.delta = delta
        self.gamma = gamma
        self.epsilon = epsilon

    def forward(self, y_pred, y_true):
        #y_pred=y_pred.size()[1]
        y_pred = torch.clamp(y_pred, self.epsilon, 1. - self.epsilon)
        cross_entropy = -y_true * torch.log(y_pred)
        
    # Calculate losses separately for each class, only suppressing background class
        back_ce = torch.pow(1 - y_pred[:,0,:,:], self.gamma) * cross_entropy[:,0,:,:]
        back_ce =  (1 - self.delta) * back_ce

        fore_ce = cross_entropy[:,1,:,:]
        fore_ce = self.delta * fore_ce

        loss = torch.mean(torch.sum(torch.stack([back_ce, fore_ce], axis=-1), axis=-1))
        return loss
```

I am calling this function as ;

```
citerion = AFL()
loss=criterion(outputs,labels.view(1, -1))
loss.backward()
optimizer.step()
```

This giving me error as ;

```
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-178-fe998ec13e82> in <module>
     20         print(outputs.shape)
     21         print(labels.shape)
---> 22         loss=criterion(outputs,labels)
     23         #model.zero_grad()
     24 

D:\software\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py in _call_impl(self, *input, **kwargs)
   1128         if not (self._backward_hooks or self._forward_hooks or self._forward_pre_hooks or _global_backward_hooks
   1129                 or _global_forward_hooks or _global_forward_pre_hooks):
-> 1130             return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
   1131         # Do not call functions when jit is used
   1132         full_backward_hooks, non_full_backward_hooks = [], []

<ipython-input-173-0ace81c245e8> in forward(self, y_pred, y_true)
     71         #y_pred=y_pred.size()[1]
     72         y_pred = torch.clamp(y_pred, self.epsilon, 1. - self.epsilon)
---> 73         cross_entropy = -y_true * torch.log(y_pred)
     74 
     75         # Calculate losses separately for each class, only suppressing background class

RuntimeError: The size of tensor a (64) must match the size of tensor b (7) at non-singleton dimension 1
```

these are my corresponding layer dimensions:

```
torch.Size([64, 3, 150, 150])
torch.Size([64, 32, 139, 139])
torch.Size([64, 32, 69, 69])
torch.Size([64, 64, 33, 33])
torch.Size([64, 128, 15, 15])
torch.Size([64, 64, 6, 6])
torch.Size([64, 128])
torch.Size([64, 64])
torch.size([64,7])
```

however, 64 is my batch size and 7 is the number of classes. why this error is coming ? i am unable to figure out. can someone tell me whre i am doing wrong?

Comment: Please include the full error text, also try making the last layer `[64, 7]`

Comment: @Caridorc hiii,full error text i have added and also my last layer is [64,7]. this also i edited .in criterion(outputs,labels). outputs= [64,7] and labels=[64]. this is where size mismatch is happening.

Comment: Ah ok, if so try making the last layer [64, 64]

Comment: but my number of classes is 7. so it should take 7 in last layer i think.  @Caridorc i did what you said and it is giving   back_ce = torch.pow(1 - y_pred[:,0,:,:], self.gamma) * cross_entropy[:,0,:,:]
     77         back_ce =  (1 - self.delta) * back_ce
     78 

IndexError: too many indices for tensor of dimension 2

Comment: Ah ok, so try printing the shapes of y_true  and y_pred to find the cause of the problem, also try putting batch size to 32 to make debugging easier so it is different from layer size

Comment: @Caridorc y_pred [32,7] & y_true [32] which is same as that of outputs and labels.why it is not taking ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251329/discussion-between-madhusmita-sahoo-and-caridorc).

Comment: I would appreciate if you announced your findings later. Thank you in advance